# C++ - Pass a class name as parameter

Tags: c++, class, parameters, factory-pattern

I have an abstract class. It's a factory.

So other factories can be inherited from this class.

I want to pass that class as an argument to a function.

How do I do that ?

```
void Gui::registerControlFactory(std::string type, ControlFactory controlFactory)
{
    registeredControls[type] = controlFactory;
}
```

here is the abstract class

```
static class ControlFactory
{
public:
    virtual Control* createControl(json j)=0;
};
```

and this is the class I want to register through my registerControlFactory function above

```
static class MyControlsFactory : public ControlFactory
{
    Control* createControl(json j)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

I wanna be able to be able to:

```
gui->registerControlFactory("sometype", MyControlsFactory );
```

I get an error :

> **Type name is not allowed**

How can I do this in C++?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the type of `registeredControls`?

Comment: `registerControlFactory` accepts a single `ControlFactory` object, not the entire `ControlFactory` class. You need to create an instance of a `MyControlsFactory` and pass it to the function. However, be aware that when you accept an argument of type `ControlFactory` by value, it gets sliced. So you probably also have to redesign `registeredControls` and `registerControlFactory`.

Comment: registeredControls is just a map std::map<std::string, ControlFactory*> registeredControls;

Comment: I wanted to avoid instanciating MyControlsFactory ...it's a static class

Comment: If your map holds `ControlFactory*`, then it seems that you don't want to pass a **class name**.  You want to pass a **pointer**.  Your map is expecting that parameter to be a pointer.

Comment: What is a "static class"?

Comment: yeah I know but I wanted to replace the class instance by a class type or something...anyway it refuses a static class without variables, so I just instanciate it and basta...damn C++

Comment: There is no such thing in C++ as a "static class". Putting `static class` is defining that class and then instantiating a static variable of that type.

Comment: `static class` is probably not doing what you're expecting it to do. You can do `static class c { } var;` to declare a static variable and the class at the same time.

Comment: Unrelated to the question asked, but I'm concerned that every parameter is passed by value (copies) and every return type is a raw pointer (leaks).  And as mentioned, your compiler is certainly refusing your "`static class`".

Answer (score 2):

To get the behavior you're probably looking for, you'll want to swap things to pointers:

```
// the interface will look like:
void Gui::registerControlFactory(std::string type, std::unqiue_ptr<ControlFactory> controlFactory)

// and then when registering:
gui->registerControlFactory("sometype", std::make_unique<MyControlsFactory>());
```

If you want to avoid creating the class altogether (which is sounds like is your goal), you could switch to `std::function< Control()>` instead of `ControlFactory`s:

```
using Factory = std::function<Control()>;
void Gui::registerControlFactory(std::string type, Factory controlFactory) {
    // assuming this is a std::map<std::string, Factory>
    registeredControls[type] = std::move(controlFactory);
}

// then you could use it like:
gui->registerControlFactory("sometype", [](){ return build_control_thing(); });
```

Also I don't think C++ has a notion of a `static class` so that keyword can probably be omitted (assuming it compiles in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

You generally pass objects, or references and pointers to objects, around; C++ can handle type names as parameters only in templates.

The declaration `void Gui::registerControlFactory(std::string type, ControlFactory controlFactory)` seems odd, given that ControlFactory is an abstract type that cannot be instantiated. (If you come C# or Java make sure to understand that in C++ objects are passed around, not references, unless a parameter is explicitly declared a reference.)

What I would expect here as a general pattern is a reference or a pointer to the base class which enables you to pass a reference or pointer to a derived class implementing this interface. That implementation would have a constructor and no pure virtual functions any longer, so one could readily create objects of that derived factory type.

If the declaration were `void Gui::registerControlFactory(std::string type, ControlFactory *controlFactory)` you would simply say something like

```
gui->registerControlFactory("sometype", new MyControlsFactory);
```

This assumes that the GUI takes ownership of the factory and disposes it when done, or that the GUI's lifetime is that of the program anyway so that no deallocation is necessary. If that is not the case you need to memorize the address of the new control factory somewhere before passing it to the gui.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to store the types in a map and instantiate an object based on the key and what type is stored in the map. C++ can't do this how you think, so you'll have to work around it.

One option would be to store lambdas in the map. Something like:

```
using ControlBuilder = std::function<Control*(const json&)>;
using FactoryMap = std::map<std::string, ControlBuilder>;

FactoryMap registeredControls;

void Gui::registerControlFactory(std::string type, ControlBuilder buildFunc)
{
    registeredControls[type] = buildFunc;
}
```

So now you can do something like:

```
gui->registerControlFactory("sometype", [](const json& j)
    { 
         MyControlsFactory factory; 
         return factory.createControl(j);
    });
```

This won't instantiate the `MyControlsFactory` object until you're ready to call it, which you can do like so:

```
auto control = registeredControls["sometype"](somejsonobject);
```

Comment: idea to use `std::function` is good, but lambda which creates `factory` for each invocation is bad.